# MySql Insert Into Select Sum

Tags: mysql, database

TABLE ONE DATA - `po_header`

```
PO_ID   PROJ_ID SUP_ID  TOT_SUM         SUBM_DATE  
32      5555    AccAYOU 99.00           2016-11-29 
33      5555    AccAYOU 990.00          2016-11-29 
34      25412   AccAYOU 248778595.08    2016-11-30
```

TABLE TWO DATA - `po_details`

```
PO_ID   amount
32      110.00
33      1500000.00
34      565079266.00
34      1.00
```

How can I Run the following SQL ?

```
    INSERT INTO po_header (TOT_SUM) VALUES (SELECT SUM(amount) 
    FROM po_details WHERE PO_ID = '34') WHERE PO_ID ='34';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even it's un correct syntax but this is what you want:

```
UPDATE po_header h 
 SET TOT_SUM = (Select sum(amount) From po_details d Where d.po_id = h.po_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE po_header SET TOT_SUM = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM po_details WHERE PO_ID='34') WHERE PO_ID='34';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!